# no route to host container registry

Tags: docker

After installing docker (ubuntu) the default 172 ip was replaced with 10.200.x.x

```
sudo ip addr add dev docker0 10.200.200.90/24
sudo ip addr del dev docker0 172.17.0.1/16
```

The machine's ip is 10.203.32.90

Then running a private container registry with the basic command:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

But then push to the registry fails with "no route to host"

```
docker push 10.203.32.90:5000/myimage
```

What have I done wrong or forgotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

> docker network ls

47ebbf46f26d   bridge    bridge    local

> docker network inspect bridge

the bridge ip was still 172.17.0.0/16

So alter the bridge ip in daemon.json

> cat /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
    "bip": "10.200.200.90/24",
}
```

restart docker daemon and bridge is working and we can push to the registry